# Meteor Tutorial: Stuck After step 10

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

A total newbie to web development. Checking out meteor tutorial which creates a simple checklist. (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/security-with-methods). Everything went smooth till step 9. At step 10 after removing insecure package

```
meteor remove insecure
```

which blocks editing from client side unless signed, all the functionality stopped working even after signing up for an account, I'm unable to create, delete and update tasks. Can you anyone give some input on how to make this app funcational again? You can check out my app at http://checklisted.meteor.com/

Thank you

Comment: did you add the required methods on the server?

Answer (score 0):

What the insecure package does is basically

```
Tasks.allow({
  insert: function () {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function () {
    return true;
  },
  update: function () {
    return true;
  },
});
```

Having this in your server code should restore all "editing" functionality right away. But this is insecure so don't do that :)

To read more about defining privileges look here:

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow

Also, have you proceed to the next steps in the tutorial? I think they're proposing another solution there - defining custom methods - which should also solve your problem.